# Incrementing a displayed number upon a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to increment the number displayed by the *h3* tag whenever the button is pressed but can't seem to find the solution to do this.

```js
var outPut = document.querySelector("#outPut");
var button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");

button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var num = 0;
  num += 1;
  outPut.innerHTML = num; 
})
```

```html
<h1>Counter</h1>
<div id="display">
  <h3 id="outPut">0</h3>
</div>
<button id="button1">Count Up</button>
<button id="button2">Count Down</button>
<button id="button3">Count Up X2</button>
<button id="button4">Count Down X2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable (`num`) in the wrong scope. Since you have declared the counter variable (`num`) inside the function, in each click the variable is created with the initial value `0`. To retain the previous value declare the variable outside the function.

Also, I will suggest you to use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` if the text is a plain text (not *htmlString*).

```js
var outPut = document.querySelector("#outPut");
var button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");
var num = 0;
button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  num += 1;
  outPut.textContent = num; 
})
```

```html
<h1>Counter</h1>
<div id="display">
  <h3 id="outPut">0</h3>
</div>
<button id="button1">Count Up</button>
<button id="button2">Count Down</button>
<button id="button3">Count Up X2</button>
<button id="button4">Count Down X2</button>
```

Comment: To explain a bit, in JavaScript, variables have function-based scope. This means that functions determine where a variable lives and has effect. The event listener here is a function, which means that if you declare the `num` inside it, it dies at the end, and gets redeclared the next time the button is clicked -- i.e. it starts over. In this answer the variable is moved up a level, out of the function, so it persists between clicks.

Comment: Also I would suggest to change ```outPut.innerHTML = num;``` to                        ```outPut.textContent = num;``` as he is changing only the text and not ```HTML``` element..